# How to get rid of the margins between the panes and the sashes in iwidget::panedwindow?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

When using [`iwidgets::panedwindow`](http://incrtcl.sourceforge.net/iwidgets/manpages/iwidgets3.0/panedwindow.n.html) I couldn't get rid of the margins between the panes and the sashes (shown in blue arrows in the small picture). Is there a way to get rid of them, so that the pane will be next to the sash, like in [`ttk::panedwindow`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_panedwindow.htm)?

A picture of a form using `iwidgit::panedwindow`:

[image]

A close picture of the "problem":

[image]

A picture of (almost) the same form using `ttk::panedwindow`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the documentation you link to, I'd estimate that the problem is probably a mix of the default `-margin` on panes you create (8 pixels, according to documentation) and the `-sashwidth` and `-thickness` overall widget options (which default to 10 and 3 pixels, respectively).

You can either set the `-margin` at creation time or update it with the `paneconfigure` method (which is missing its documentation, but is shown in the example in the documentation), and the `-sashwidth` and `-thickness` options are set either at widget creation time or via the `configure` method (as per the standard pattern of Tk widgets).

Setting all the options mentioned above to zero is unlikely to produce a usable widget, but the pane margins can probably be reduced to zero without ill effect (they describe the space between the interior widget and the edges of its pane).